# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, which of the following relationships between $q^2$ and $n$ hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Preamble #1:  In what follows, we take $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ to be the *sum of the divisors*, and denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.)

(Preamble #2:  My sincerest apologies for the somewhat very long post -- I just had to put in all the details into one place for ease of quick reference later.)

**PROBLEM**

> If $q^k n^2$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with Euler prime $q$, which of the following relationships between $q^2$ and $n$ hold?
>
> > **(A)** $$q^2 < \sigma(q^2) < n < \sigma(n)$$
> > **(B)** $$q^2 < n < \sigma(q^2) < \sigma(n)$$
> > **(C)** $$n < \sigma(n) < q^2 < \sigma(q^2)$$
> > **(D)** $$n < q^2 < \sigma(n) < \sigma(q^2)$$

**PRELIMINARIES**

**(0)** Of course, first of all, note that $q^2 \neq n$ since $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**(1)** Note that
$$\frac{q^2}{n}+\frac{n}{q^2} < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < 2\cdot\bigg(\frac{q^2}{n}+\frac{n}{q^2}\bigg).$$
Consequently, we know that
$$\frac{q^2}{n}+\frac{n}{q^2} \text{ is bounded from above } \iff \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} \text{ is bounded from above.}$$
In general, since the function $f(z) := z + (1/z)$ is not bounded from above, this means that we do not expect
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
to be bounded from above.

**(2)** $n < q^2 \implies k = 1$ [[Dris, 2012]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html)

**(3)** $$1 < I(q^2) \leq \frac{q^2 + q + 1}{q^2} = 1+\frac{1}{q}+\bigg(\frac{1}{q}\bigg)^2 \leq 1+\frac{1}{5}+\bigg(\frac{1}{5}\bigg)^2 = \frac{25+5+1}{5} = \frac{31}{25}$$
since $q$ being the Euler prime implies that $q$ is prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, therefore $q \geq 5$.

Now, $1 < I(n) < 2$ since $n > 1$ is deficient, $n$ being a proper factor of the (odd) perfect number $q^k n^2$.

Consequently,
$$1 < I({q^2}n) = I(q^2)I(n) = \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < 2\cdot\frac{31}{25} = \frac{62}{25}.$$

**(4)** It follows from **(1)** and **(3)** that the following hold:

**(a)** $\sigma(n) \neq \sigma(q^2)$

*Proof*:  Assume that $\sigma(n) = \sigma(q^2)$.  Then we have (by **(3)**)
$$I(q^2) = \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{q^2} = \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < \frac{31}{25}$$
and
$$I(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n} < 2.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < 2+\frac{31}{25}=\frac{81}{25}.$$
This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is bounded from above, contradicting **(1)**.

**(b)** $\sigma(q^2) \neq n$.

Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(q^2)=n$.  Then we have (from **(3)**)
$$1\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} = \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < \frac{62}{25}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}=1+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}<1+\frac{62}{25}=\frac{87}{25}.$$
This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is bounded from above, contradicting **(1)**.

The proof for the following is similar to that of **(b)**:

**(c)** $\sigma(n) \neq q^2$

**MAIN RESULTS**

The proofs of the succeeding three lemmas are trivial.

**Lemma 1.**  The inequality
$$I(q^2) + I(n) < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is true if and only if the biconditional
$$q^2 < n \iff \sigma(q^2) < \sigma(n)$$
is true.

**Lemma 2.**  The inequality
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < I(q^2) + I(n)$$
is true if and only if the biconditional
$$q^2 < n \iff \sigma(n) < \sigma(q^2)$$
is true.

**Lemma 3.**  The equation
$$I(q^2) + I(n) = \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is true if and only if either $q^2 = n$ or $\sigma(q^2)=\sigma(n)$ hold.

We now prove our first main result:

**Theorem 1.** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then the inequality
$$I(q^2) + I(n) < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
holds.

*Proof*:  Suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} \leq I(q^2)+I(n).$$

Since $I(q^2) \leq 31/25$ and $I(n) < 2$, this implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < 2 + \frac{31}{25} = \frac{81}{25}$$
so that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is bounded from above, contradicting **(1)**.

By using **Lemma 1**, we are able to obtain the following Corollary to **Theorem 1**.

**Corollary 2**.  If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then the biconditionals
$$q^2 < n \iff \sigma(q^2) < \sigma(n) \iff \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
hold.

**Proof**: Trivial.

> > **Note that *Corollary 2* proves that the list of inequalities given in the *Problem Statement* exhausts all possible cases.**

We now claim that:

**Theorem 3**.  If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then $q^2 < \sigma(n)$ and $n < \sigma(q^2)$ cannot be both true.

*Proof*:

Suppose that both
$$1 < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}$$
and
$$1 < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
hold.
Then it follows that both
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} = I({q^2}n) < \frac{62}{25}$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} = I({q^2}n) < \frac{62}{25}$$
hold.
This means that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2} < 2\cdot\frac{62}{25} = \frac{124}{25}$$
which implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^2)}{n}+\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^2}$$
is bounded from above, contradicting **(1)**.

> > **Note that *Theorem 3* immediately rules out *Case (B)* and *Case (D)* above.**

**INQUIRIES**

We are left to consider the following two (2) remaining cases:

> > **(A)** $$q^2 < \sigma(q^2) < n < \sigma(n)$$
> > **(C)** $$n < \sigma(n) < q^2 < \sigma(q^2)$$
>
> *Question #1* By this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1843814/28816), we know (?) that the implication $n < q^{k+1} \implies k \neq 1$ is true if and only if $q^2 < n$.  Can this result be improved?
>
> *Question #2* Following this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918871/28816), it is conjectured that $k \neq 1$.  This would follow if we could rule out $q = q^k < \sigma(q) = \sigma(q^k) < n < \sigma(n)$.  (That is, if we could prove that $\sigma(q^k) < n$ is false.)  To what extent can a proof along this thread of thought be pursued, given Brown's arguments for a partial proof of $q^k < n$ in [A Partial Proof of a Conjecture of Dris](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) and the considerations in this MSE post?

Answer (score 1):

This post (and other related posts) seem to prove the following assertion:

**CONJECTURE**  If there is an odd perfect number, then there are infinitely many of them.

*Proof*:  Suppose that there are only a finite number of odd perfect numbers.

This means that there exists an effectively computable constant $\mathcal{C}$ such that
$$q^k n^2 < \mathcal{C}.$$

Since $q^k < n^2$ [[Dris, 2012]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), then it follows that
$$q^{2k} < {q^k}{n^2} < \mathcal{C}.$$
This implies that
$$q^2 \leq q^{2k} < \mathcal{C},$$
so that
$$q < \mathcal{C}^{1/2}$$
which means that the Euler prime is bounded from above.

Note that we also have
$$n^2 < {q^k}{n^2} < \mathcal{C}$$
so that $n < \mathcal{C}^{1/2}$, that is to say, the square root of the non-Euler part (which is $n$) is bounded from above.

Going back to the considerations in this post, we either have $q^2 < n$ or $n < q^2$.  (In both cases, note that we have $q < n$ by [[Brown, 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591)], [[Starni, 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02144)], and [[Dris, 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0906v19.pdf)].)

In the first case, we have
$$q^2 < n < \mathcal{C}^{1/2}$$
so that
$$\frac{q^2}{n}+\frac{n}{q^2} < 1 + \frac{\mathcal{C}^{1/2}}{25}.$$
This contradicts **(1)** in the question.

In the second case, we have
$$q < n < q^2$$
so that $n > {10}^{500}$, and
$$\frac{q^2}{n}+\frac{n}{q^2} < 1 + \frac{\mathcal{C}}{{10}^{500}}.$$
Again, this contradicts **(1)** in the question, and the **CONJECTURE** in this answer is proved.